# Webpack 2: Watch external files

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack-2

I have a project that uses source files external to the project. Effectively, there is the actual project source code (an Typescript/Angular 2 application, lets call it the 'core' stuff), and this is a generic web application that is meant to be the base code that consumes these external source files.

The external files include additional stuff-- that could be SCSS files, images, evn additional JS. The way I want this to work is that webpack copies these external files from any source directory (this is critical, it is not part of the core project) to a local .tmp directory. The files in the .tmp directory are worked on along with the core src files to generate the prod output.

I can't figure out how to add these additional external source files to the watch list. Effectively what I'm looking to do is watch that directory and as things change, it re-copies the affected files to the local .tmp directory and triggers a recompile.

Presently I have to restart webpack and have a very very ugly solution using Grunt to watch the additional files. It's nasty but these kinds of workarounds have historically been what I've had to do with webpack.

Does anyone have a better solution? Ideally I'd like to not have to mix grunt with webpack. Webpack should be able to do this, but its hard to know whether there's an existing plugin for this or what the best approach would be.

Also, please spare the "look for it on google" or "read the docs" comments. I've combed through it all, hard, and have not found anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused - if the files in your `.tmp` directory aren't a dependency of your webpack application, why do you need to trigger a webpack refresh?

Comment: They are, but they get combined with the other source files, creating a temporary working directory from which the combined source files (a full set) are worked from. For instance, custom SASS files that can be provided by the consumer can be factored in here, etc. Webpack needs to rerun when the contents of .tmp are changed, effectively requiring a different watcher for the external files.

Comment: ...Think of the actual core source as an incomplete set of code (though it would compile fine on its own, w/o the external resources its basically a useless generic shell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now Webpack doesn't watch external files out-of-the-box . You need a plugin for that.

Basically idea is to have a file watcher module chokidar / watch , listening to the file change , and when there is a change, restart the webpack compilation phase . Webpack plugins can access the compilation object and we you need to hook it to a compiler phase i.e. 'emit' , 'after-emit' etc.

This Webpack plugin exactly solves your problem - https://www.npmjs.com/package/filewatcher-webpack-plugin .

Comment: Yeah, I ended up rolling my own. I did take a look at this though, and it'll be an acceptable answer I think. Thanks.

Comment: @dudewad could you send a link to your plugin, please

Comment: It's not an npm package and I dont even remember what project I made it for. Plus at this point it is probably broken against later versions of webpack. Sorry.